# Product "save and continue" redirect to dashboard?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

When I add

> an iframe

into the product description textarea to display the video on the product page and then click on

> save & continue

button, it redirects to the dashboard.

But If I remove the iframe then it works fine.

Can I add iframe into description Textarea?

Comment: any solution on this issue?